# Need Raspberry pi 4 to send servo commands to pixhawk to control rc car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence, pwm, servo

Hello I am working on a group project of trying to complete an autonomous rc car. There a pixhawk that has the main control and commands to navigate the car. However there raspberry pi that's doing path tracking that will eventually need control over the servo. Is there a way fro the pixhawk to receive pwm values that will set the servo in real time. Keep in mind that the pixhawk is having control over the servo as well. Do anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode the output of your RC receiver first. Just check on what the receiver is sending to pixhawk by connecting any microcontroller/microprocessor at the output channel of receiver, and generate the same ppm signal using your raspberry pi.
Else, you can directly connect your raspberry with pixhawk using RX/TX(UART) pins.

There is a tutorial on it [here](https://www.instructables.com/Autonomous-Drone-Using-RPi/)

Comment: Thank You! You are saying that I can send ppm signal from raspberry pi to the rc reciever that will lead to pixhawk? or no. What is the connection/logic between that. Any documentation on the first suggestion I can refer to? @astrick

Comment: No, I am saying you can receive ppm signals from RC Receiver of individual channels on Raspberri pi  and send the same ppm from raspberry pi next time without any receiver to. By doing this pixhawk will not be able to recognize whether the ppm is coming from receiver or from any other source. This way you can control pixhawk autonomously.

Comment: Thank you! for your help! last question would you suggest using pigpio python library to generate this ppm?@astrick

Comment: Yes! That will do the task for you.